# How can I see the true, non-adaptive histogram for my photograph?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, exposure, histogram

Given that both Lightroom and (as far as I know) Photoshop use adaptive histograms, is there any way to look at my photos using a true histogram?

By true I mean showing a true distribution of greyscale values across the x axis.

Answer (score 4):

Have you check [RawDigger](http://www.rawdigger.com). As far as I know it show really raw histogram

Answer (score 0):

Try ImageJ http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/ together with dcraw used as import plugin to read RAW files.